# Removing the BackStack Entry in MetroStyle Application

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

How can I implement removing the backStack Entry in Metro style applications?

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.SetNavigationState("1,0");
```

will clear the navigation history for you.

Comment: This worked for me as far as I can tell.  I used this trick to remove the first page in my Windows 8 app.  I used this line of code prior to navigating away from that page.  I tried it first in a few other places, like the LoadState on the following page, and it had some weird side effects.

Comment: This clears the navigation state entirely, which can be done much more cleanly as ZombieSheep suggested below. But it does not remove just the one most recent page from the stack as the question suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer useful:

[How to clear Backstack of the frame and start afresh](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e73af16b-a90b-4ab0-885d-33d9252eb7e8)

Write your own NavigationService and store the navigationstate in the constructor.

```
string state;

public NavigationService(Frame mainFrame)
{
    state = mainFrame.GetNavigationState();

_mainFrame = mainFrame;
_mainFrame.Navigating += _mainFrame_Navigating;
}
```

Then implement this method on the service and call it when needed:

```
    public void ClearBackstack()
    {
        _mainFrame.SetNavigationState(state);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible.  If you want to clear the back stack entirely (e.g. if you have a "home" button), you can use the code supplied in the LayoutAwarePage.cs file in the grid sample app.

```
if (this.Frame != null)
{
    while (this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

While this doesn't actually clear the stack, it does take you back to the program's start location and there will be no further back-direction entries in the list.  If you want to back out of a dead-end page by pressing a button, you could modify this behaviour to step back a number of pages and effectively remove the back entries.