# Clearing the backstack of the win8 app after a usual logout?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I wanted to clear the backstack of a win8 application  after a usual logout feature.
I have thought of 3 ways : although none of them works perfectly

1.Create a new frame after logout and navigate to LoginScreen

> problem - after navigating to login screen the page does not scroll
>   when keyboard is up.

2.Loop while the backstack is 0 and keep calling Frame.Goback.

> problem - it calls the onnavigatedTo of every page as it iterates over
>   them.

3.get and Set Navigation States

> problem: after i set the navigation state of the LoginScreen after
>   logout it works fine BUT every page which i navigate to after that
>   does not call its constructor.

Please help if any one has had success with logout kind feature.

Win8+XAML+C#.

Comment: If your login screen does not have a back button. Just navigate to the login screen without creating a new frame. Why would you want to clear the backstack then?

Comment: @userSeven7s I don't know if it solves your issues, but did you try [`frame.SetNavigationState("1,0");`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13015697/1822514)

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009475/removing-the-backstack-entry-in-metrostyle-application

Answer (score 0):

try this in loaded event

```
 this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
```