# how to determine if the previous page is the searchresults.xaml page

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

Situation:

Application is a Windows8 metro store application.

When a user uses the search charm and a result is found in my application, it goes to the searchresults.xaml page. User then taps on one of the items, and is redirected (navigates) to the details page. The details page has a back button with Frame.GoBack as the code.

What I wish to accomplish is if the user taps the back button, and the previous page is the searchresults page, user should be redirected to the home page.

so, is there a way to determine this?

code to navigate to the details page already uses the navigation parameter.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When your app is activated via search, [OnSearchActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onsearchactivated.aspx) will fire, so you can use that opportunity to record that particular path through the app and act accordingly.  You could probably incorporate your own navigation service ([touched on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009475/removing-the-backstack-entry-in-metrostyle-application)) as well for a less fragile implementation.

I wonder though if you really should/want to do this?

1. Users may be surprised that a back button action takes them to a page they never visited.
2. What if they decided that the item that brought them to the details page wasn't really the search result they were truly interested in.  There's no way to navigate back to the search results - they'd have to reissue the search anew.

I'd say an app bar button that let's them optionally go to the home page would be more intuitive, or perhaps include a button/glyph on the detail page itself if you're concerned about discoverability.